unable to upload an image: HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:1328 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: skipping cycle due to overload
im trying to upload an image and a video using TUS KIT, first time everything goes well,
but when i close the screen, and retry uploading a new video, im getting the following logs:
nw_connection_add_timestamp_locked_on_nw_queue [C24] Hit maximum timestamp count, will start dropping events
nw_read_request_report [C16] Receive failed with error "Operation timed out"
107299          HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:1328  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: skipping cycle due to overload

i created a separate manager as follow:
final class XManager {
 var tusClient: TUSClient?
 init() {
    setupTUSClient()
  }

//Everything goes well here
 private func setupTUSClient() {
    let endpoint = URL(string: "https://abcd.tv/files")!
    let sessionIdentifier = "identifier"

    do {
      tusClient = try TUSClient(server: endpoint, sessionIdentifier: sessionIdentifier, sessionConfiguration: .background(withIdentifier: sessionIdentifier), chunkSize: 100*1024 )//
      tusClient?.delegate = self
      tusClient?.start()
    } catch {
      print("Failed to initialize TUSClient: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }

This works only the first time, the delegate functions work well, and i get the final url when done.
but when closing and retry to upload a new video, the delegate methods stop working, and i get the errors mentioned on the top
 func uploadVideoOrImage(videoURL: URL, uploadType: UploadType) {
    tusClient?.stopAndCancelAll()
    let url = videoURL
      self.uploadType = uploadType
    if uploadType == .image {
      hasSentImageURL = false
    } else {
      hasSentVideoURL = false
    }
      guard let tusClient = tusClient else {
          print("TUSClient is not initialized")
          return
      }
      do {
          try tusClient.uploadFileAt(filePath: videoURL)
      } catch let error {
          print("Upload failed to start: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
  }

